# Enterprise laptop doesn't recognize WiFi

Tags: wifi-driver

My cousin is using an enterprise laptop for home work, but for some reason she can't connect to her home WiFi. The laptop isn't able to detect any WiFi networks, although she used to be able to detect and connect to the network.

Whenever I troubleshoot for possible issues, Windows Vista is telling me the switch for wireless reception is turned off, but I'm sure it's turned on (If I turn it on, the HP Wireless Assistant tells me it's turned on, so...).

But if I take a look at the settings, I get this message (sorry it's in Dutch):

[image]

So for some reason, the WLAN reception is deactivated and I cannot activate this...

Does this have something to do with the laptop being an enterprise laptop? Or is there a simple setting I missed?

The most recent driver of the Wireless Network Card (Intel Wireless 5100) is installed.

Comment: is the chipset enabled from the BIOS?

Comment: Thanks! Silly question though, how do I check this :$

Comment: I believe hitting F10 when your laptop is starting, before Windows boot screen appears should get you into the BIOS.